# Edit recorded macro, custom sort order

Tags: vba, excel

I need a custom sort order of a table.
The sort order is dependant of the font color.

First the recorded macro of custom sort order:

```
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("onsdag", "torsdag", "fredag", _
    "lördag", "söndag", "måndag", "tisdag") ' wednsday -> tuesday sort order
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A5031") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I2:I5031") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "onsdag,torsdag,fredag,lördag,söndag,måndag,tisdag", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:I5031")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

The above code does what it's supposed to do.
Then to make the custom sort order even more custom I tried this code:

```
shtD = "Data 1703"

If Sheets(shtD).Range("V3").Font.Color = vbGreen Then
    ordn = "måndag,tisdag,onsdag,torsdag,fredag,lördag,söndag" ' Monday -> Sunday
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("måndag", "tisdag", "onsdag", "torsdag", "fredag", "lördag", "söndag") 

ElseIf Sheets(shtD).Range("W3").Font.Color = vbGreen Then
    ordn = "tisdag,onsdag,torsdag,fredag,lördag,söndag, måndag" ' Tuesday -> Monday
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("tisdag", "onsdag", "torsdag", "fredag", "lördag", "söndag", "måndag")

ElseIf Sheets(shtD).Range("X3").Font.Color = vbGreen Then
    ordn = "onsdag,torsdag,fredag,lördag,söndag,måndag,tisdag"
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("onsdag", "torsdag", "fredag", "lördag", "söndag", "måndag", "tisdag")

ElseIf Sheets(shtD).Range("Y3").Font.Color = vbGreen Then
    ordn = "torsdag,fredag,lördag,söndag,måndag,tisdag,onsdag"
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("torsdag", "fredag", "lördag", "söndag", "måndag", "tisdag", "onsdag")

ElseIf Sheets(shtD).Range("Z3").Font.Color = vbGreen Then
    ordn = "fredag,lördag,söndag,måndag,tisdag,onsdag,torsdag"
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("fredag", "lördag", "söndag", "måndag", "tisdag", "onsdag", "torsdag")

ElseIf Sheets(shtD).Range("AA3").Font.Color = vbGreen Then
    ordn = "lördag,söndag,måndag,tisdag,onsdag,torsdag,fredag"
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("lördag", "söndag", "måndag", "tisdag", "onsdag", "torsdag", "fredag")

ElseIf Sheets(shtD).Range("AB3").Font.Color = vbGreen Then
    ordn = "söndag,måndag,tisdag,onsdag,torsdag,fredag,lördag"
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("söndag", "måndag", "tisdag", "onsdag", "torsdag", "fredag", "lördag")

Else
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("SAP 1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheets("SAP 1").Activate


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A5031") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I2:I5031") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    ordn, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:I5031")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

In short I create the `CustomOrder` string and the `Application.AddCustomList ListArray` first then apply it to the recorded macro.
But I get error 13, incompatible types on this line:
`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I2:I5031"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=ordn, DataOption:=xlSortNormal`

When I open the dialog to do a custom sort order manually the custom order does not seem to be saved. I can only see the one that I manually created when I recorded the macro.
Anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomOrder` parameter expect a `Variant` so use `CVar(`) to cast your `String` to a `Variant`

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP 1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I2:I5031") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
cVar(ordn), DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out site below. It seems you are facing issue with variable in the custom order that is described there
https://explorationsintoexcel.wordpress.com/2016/11/06/set-custom-sort-order-from-range-values-in-excel-vba/

It seems it is not possible to enter only the variable without quotation marks, but you can circumvent that by using multiple quotation marks and & to enter the variable:

```
CustomOrder:=""" & ordn & """
```